# Scripting permissions of AD Groups

Tags: sql-server

How do I script out the permissions of the AD groups? I am looking for groups that have been denied access using DENY CONNECT.

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you all `WINDOWS_GROUP` that has been denied using `DENY CONNECT SQL` at the server level.

```
USE master;
GO

SELECT 
    l.name as windowsGroupName, 
    p.state_desc, 
    p.permission_name
FROM sys.server_permissions AS p JOIN sys.server_principals AS l 
ON p.grantee_principal_id = l.principal_id
WHERE p.state_desc ='DENY'
AND l.type ='G'; --WINDOWS_GROUP only
GO
```